# How to add a SaveandContinueEdit Button to my form?

Tags: javascript, forms, magento, adminhtml

I am working on a new Magento extension, in my Adminhtml form I want to add the button "saveAndContinueEdit"

I've added this code to my Edit.php file.

```
      $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
    'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
    'class'     => 'save',
), -100);
```

But whene I click on it, I have this JavaScript error :

> Erreur : ReferenceError: saveAndContinueEdit is not defined Fichier
>   Source :
>   http://X.X.X.X/magento/index.php/slider/adminhtml_config/new/key

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how magento works, but i can see that you have upper case and lower case for the same function call: `saveandcontinue` and `saveAndContinueEdit()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your admin Block Constructor Put these lines.

```
$this->_formScripts[] = " function saveAndContinueEdit(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
    ";
```

Please remember you have to write functionality for it in PHP also.
Now in you action just have a final check that if you are getting back as param .. redirect it to referer page.

Comment: ankur.singh is right you have to :
- create the button as you did
- create the js function to submit the form with a back parameter
- edit the Controller action to handle this back parameter and redirect to the previous page (look at those functionnality in other page that have Save and Continue

Comment: Ok this is clear Thanks, but i can't get the id !!   Zend_Debug::dump( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')); is null

Comment: If you are on new page , magento will make url as */new whereas on edit page url will be like */edit/id/1 . On edit page submission you will get id from request object but in new case we don't(can't) get id so you have to write your code to take care of it. Incase of new entry, you have to get ID from model object after save.

if(!$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')){ $id = $model->getId(); }